# Can't launch Kodi - No display found + few simple questions

Tags: linux, debian, kodi

I installed kodi on my bananian, a variation of debian, on banana pro via apt-get. I can't launch it tough. As the title states, in the error log file it says: `ERROR: GLX Error: No Display found`. Whole log file below. I tried googling it, but no luck there.

```
############## Kodi CRASH LOG ###############

################ SYSTEM INFO ################
 Date: Tue Apr  5 21:05:08 UTC 2016
 Kodi Options: 
 Arch: armv7l
 Kernel: Linux 3.4.108-bananian #2 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 13 06:08:25 UTC 2015
 Release: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
############## END SYSTEM INFO ##############

############### STACK TRACE #################
gdb not installed, can't get stack trace.
############# END STACK TRACE ###############

################# LOG FILE ##################

21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: special://profile/ is mapped to: special://masterprofile/
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Starting Kodi from Debian (15.2 Git: (unknown)). Platform: Linux ARM (Thumb) 32-bit
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Using Debug Kodi from Debian x32 build
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Kodi from Debian compiled from 15.2+dfsg1-1~bpo8+1 by GCC 4.9.2 for Linux ARM (Thumb) 32-bit version 3.16.7 (200711)
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Running on Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie), kernel: Linux ARM 32-bit version 3.4.108-bananian
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: FFmpeg version: 2.8.1-1~bpo8+1
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Host CPU: ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l), 2 cores available
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: ARM Features: Neon disabled
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: special://xbmc/ is mapped to: /usr/share/kodi
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: special://xbmcbin/ is mapped to: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/kodi
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: special://masterprofile/ is mapped to: /root/.kodi/userdata
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: special://home/ is mapped to: /root/.kodi
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: special://temp/ is mapped to: /root/.kodi/temp
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: The executable running is: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/kodi/kodi.bin
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Local hostname: bananapi
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Log File is located: /root/.kodi/temp/kodi.log
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
21:05:03 T:2973908992   DEBUG: ConsoleKit.Manager: org.freedesktop.DBus.GLib.UnmappedError.GDbusErrorQuark.Code2 - GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
21:05:03 T:2973908992   DEBUG: UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown - The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
21:05:03 T:2973908992   DEBUG: ConsoleKit.Manager: org.freedesktop.DBus.GLib.UnmappedError.GDbusErrorQuark.Code2 - GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
21:05:03 T:2973908992   DEBUG: DeviceKit.Power: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown - The name org.freedesktop.DeviceKit.Disks was not provided by any .service files
21:05:03 T:2973908992   DEBUG: UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown - The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
21:05:03 T:2973908992  NOTICE: load settings...
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CSettings: loaded settings definition from special://xbmc/system/settings/settings.xml
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CSettings: loaded settings definition from special://xbmc/system/settings/linux.xml
21:05:04 T:2973908992   ERROR: PulseAudio: Failed to connect context
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: PulseAudio might not be running. Context was not created.
21:05:04 T:2906121040  NOTICE: Thread FDEventMonitor start, auto delete: false
21:05:04 T:2973908992    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "surround71" for playback
21:05:04 T:2973908992    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "surround51" for playback
21:05:04 T:2973908992    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "surround71" for playback
21:05:04 T:2973908992    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "surround40" for playback
21:05:04 T:2973908992    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "surround51" for playback
21:05:04 T:2973908992    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "surround71" for playback
21:05:04 T:2973908992    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "pulse" for playback
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Found 1 Lists of Devices
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Enumerated ALSA devices:
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE:     Device 1
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : @
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Default (sunxi-CODEC sunxi PCM)
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra:
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE:         m_channels        : FL,FR
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates     : 8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,96000,192000
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     : AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S16LE
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: No settings file to load (special://xbmc/system/advancedsettings.xml)
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: No settings file to load (special://masterprofile/advancedsettings.xml)
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Default DVD Player: dvdplayer
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Default Video Player: dvdplayer
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Default Audio Player: paplayer
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Disabled debug logging due to GUI setting. Level 0.
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Log level changed to "LOG_LEVEL_NORMAL"
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Loading player core factory settings from special://xbmc/system/playercorefactory.xml.
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerCoreConfig::<ctor>: created player DVDPlayer for core 1
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerCoreConfig::<ctor>: created player oldmplayercore for core 1
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerCoreConfig::<ctor>: created player PAPlayer for core 3
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: system rules
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: hdhomerun/mms/udp
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: lastfm/shout
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: rtmp
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: rtsp
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: streams
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: aacp/sdp
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: mp2
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: dvd
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: dvdimage
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: sdp/asf
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: nsv
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: radio
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Loaded playercorefactory configuration
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Loading player core factory settings from special://masterprofile/playercorefactory.xml.
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: special://masterprofile/playercorefactory.xml does not exist. Skipping.
21:05:04 T:2973908992    INFO: creating subdirectories
21:05:04 T:2973908992    INFO: userdata folder: special://masterprofile/
21:05:04 T:2973908992    INFO: recording folder:
21:05:04 T:2973908992    INFO: screenshots folder:
21:05:04 T:2829050704  NOTICE: Thread ActiveAE start, auto delete: false
21:05:04 T:2896163664  NOTICE: Thread AESink start, auto delete: false
21:05:04 T:2896163664    INFO: CActiveAESink::OpenSink - initialize sink
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG: CActiveAESink::OpenSink - trying to open device ALSA:@
21:05:04 T:2896163664    INFO: CAESinkALSA::Initialize - Attempting to open device "@"
21:05:04 T:2896163664    INFO: CAESinkALSA::Initialize - Opened device "sysdefault"
21:05:04 T:2896163664    INFO: CAESinkALSA::InitializeHW - Your hardware does not support AE_FMT_FLOAT, trying other formats
21:05:04 T:2896163664    INFO: CAESinkALSA::InitializeHW - Using data format AE_FMT_S16NE
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::InitializeHW - Request: periodSize 2048, bufferSize 8192
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::InitializeHW - Got: periodSize 2048, bufferSize 8192
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::InitializeHW - Setting timeout to 186 ms
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::GetChannelLayout - Input Channel Count: 2 Output Channel Count: 2
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::GetChannelLayout - Requested Layout: FL,FR
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::GetChannelLayout - Got Layout: FL,FR (ALSA: none)
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG: CActiveAESink::OpenSink - ALSA Initialized:
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG:   Output Device : Default (sunxi-CODEC sunxi PCM)
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG:   Sample Rate   : 44100
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG:   Sample Format : AE_FMT_S16NE
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG:   Channel Count : 2
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG:   Channel Layout: FL,FR
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG:   Frames        : 2048
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG:   Frame Samples : 4096
21:05:04 T:2896163664   DEBUG:   Frame Size    : 4
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: Running database version Addons19
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: SECTION:LoadDLL(special://xbmcbin/system/libcpluff-arm.so)
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: Loading: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/kodi/system/libcpluff-arm.so
21:05:04 T:2973908992  NOTICE: ADDONS: Using repository repository.xbmc.org
21:05:04 T:2885677904  NOTICE: Thread RemoteControl start, auto delete: false
21:05:04 T:2885677904    INFO: LIRC Process: using: /dev/lircd
21:05:04 T:2885677904    INFO: LIRC Connect: connect failed: No such file or directory
21:05:04 T:2885677904    INFO: CRemoteControl::Process - failed to connect to LIRC, will keep retrying every 5 seconds
21:05:04 T:2973908992    INFO: CKeyboardLayoutManager: loading keyboard layouts from special://xbmc/system/keyboardlayouts...
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Arabic QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Norwegian QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Portuguese (Portugal) QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Hebrew QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Hebrew ABC" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Russian ЙЦУКЕН" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Russian АБВ" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Lithuanian AZERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Lithuanian QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Ukrainian ЙЦУКЕН" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Ukrainian АБВ" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Spanish QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Romanian QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Turkish QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Danish QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Bulgarian ЯВЕРТЪ" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Bulgarian АБВ" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Swedish QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "German QWERTZ" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Hungarian QWERTZ" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Polish QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "English QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "English AZERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "English ABC" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: CKeyboardLayoutManager: keyboard layout "Greek QWERTY" successfully loaded
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: UDisks: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown - The name org.freedesktop.UDisks was not provided by any .service files
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: DeviceKit.Disks: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown - The name org.freedesktop.DeviceKit.Disks was not provided by any .service files
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: Selected UDev as storage provider
21:05:04 T:2973908992   ERROR: GLX Error: No Display found
21:05:04 T:2973908992   FATAL: CApplication::Create: Unable to init windowing system
21:05:04 T:2973908992   DEBUG: PVRManager - destroyed
21:05:04 T:2885677904   DEBUG: Failed to connect to LIRC. Giving up.


############### END LOG FILE ################

############ END Kodi CRASH LOG #############
```

Also, I have a couple of questions that bother me and I couldn't really find the answer on the internet. Perhaps I didn't know how to word it, because this seems like some really simple stuff.
This bananian distro doesn't ship with any gui. When it boots, there is just plain shell. Should I be able to run a fullscreen app with no gui? (I installed xfce before trying to launch kodi, asking just because I don't know how exactly it works) How to force system to launch xfce, if I want it to? I also installed xorg, but same with this, not quite sure why I need it and what is the exact role of this tool.

Answer (score 0):

You do need a GUI so that you can see the Kodi interface. Using Xfce will work. Sounds like you are having issues with figuring out how to run Xfce. I found [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Xfce) article on Xfce with Debian. Below is the section pertaining to running Xfce, but if you view the article, it will go through the installation process as well as information on what Xfce is. In basic terms, it is a desktop environment.

> **With a display manager**
>
> For **GDM**, **KDM** and **LightDM** choose xfce4-session.
>
> For **slim** boot session in /etc/slim.conf:
>
> ```
> login_cmd exec ck-launch-session /bin/bash -login /etc/X11/Xsession %session
> ```
>
> You also can install [xdm](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=xdm) to login in start Xfce.
>
> **From the console**
>
> If you don't use a login manager but start Xfce from console, you need
>   to take care of few stuff in order to get a complete Xfce session with
>   full permission (mount, suspend/shutdown/hibernate etc.) This is
>   because Debian now uses ?PolicyKit/ConsoleKit to manage policies for
>   things like device and power management.
>
> - only use startx, without any argument
> - don't use a .xinitrc, add in file ~/.xsession:
>
>   exec ck-launch-session startxfce4
>
> This is because ?ConsoleKit ships an init script
>   (/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90consolekit), but the /etc/X11/Xsession.d/
>   scripts are only executed if you don't use any .xinitrc. See startx
>   (1) for more information.
>
> Then you need to fine-tune your pam installation so ?ConsoleKit can be
>   sure that your user is correctly authenticated. For that, you need to
>   install libpam-ck-connector and put before pam_ck_connector.so in
>   /etc/pam.d/common-session.
>
> ```
> session   optional  pam_loginuid.so
> ```

Comment: I successfully managed to launch xfce and only then tried launching kodi

Comment: Did you ensure that you have the proper video drivers installed @Fulaphex?

Comment: Not quite sure how to check it. I am able to start some desktop environment, so kodi should work too?

Comment: There is even more stuff wrong. When I launch lxde or xfce, go back into shell mode with ctrl+alt+f1 and try to return to desktop environment with ctrl+alt+f7 screen just keeps blinking.